# Docker java:7 image apt-get update cyclic dependencies

Tags: java, docker, debian, apt-get

I am using the official java:7 docker image. When I run apt-get update on it, it throws an error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

So when I run:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

It says unable to locate the package

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
```

Here is my /etc/apt/source.list

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
```

I understand that apt-transport-https requires "apt-get update" and vice versa. 
I can get the packages using

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.3_amd64.deb && dpkg -i apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.3_amd64.deb
```

But is there a better way ?

Comment: I just tried it (`docker run -ti java:7` + `apt-get update` inside) and it worked (I have the same sources.list). Do you use the last version (docker pull java:7) ? Do you have any extra file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was some error with that particular version and when I updated the image it works fine.